# Spring custom Generic converter not working

Tags: spring-mvc, converters

In my spring mvc web-application i use a generic converter that converts String (id) to Company by fetch using (service and dao) components

first of all in my MVC-config i add the converter like follow :

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new GenericIdToCompanyConverter(new CompanyServiceImp()));
}
```

companyService

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Qualifier("companyService")
public class CompanyServiceImp implements ICompanyService {

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("companyDAO")
    private ICompanyDao dao;


    public void setDao(ICompanyDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public Company find(Long id) throws BusinessException {
        Company current = dao.find(id);
        if(current == null) {
            throw new BusinessException("notFound");
        }
        return current;
    }
....
}
```

Generic converter :

```
public class GenericIdToCompanyConverter implements GenericConverter {

    private ICompanyService companyService;

    public GenericIdToCompanyConverter(ICompanyService companyService) {
        super();
        this.companyService = companyService;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        ConvertiblePair[] pairs = new ConvertiblePair[] { new ConvertiblePair(Number.class, Company.class), new ConvertiblePair(String.class, Company.class) };
        return ImmutableSet.copyOf(pairs);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        long id = 0;
        if( sourceType.getType() == String.class) {
            try {
                id = Long.valueOf((String) source);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }else if( sourceType.getType() == Number.class) {
            id = (Long) source;
        }else {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return companyService.find(Long.valueOf(id));
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and here the controller that receives data form (via ajax request)

```
public @ResponseBody JsonResponseBean applay(@Valid VoucherForm form, BindingResult result, Locale locale) throws BusinessException {
....
}
```

where VoucherForm has these attributes

```
public class VoucherForm{
    protected Long id;
    protected Company company;
...
}
```

when i run the application and call controller method it returns type mismatch error for company attribute
and when i execute this on debug mode i see that it fails on serviceCompany -  dao.find(id) statment where my dao is == null

Please help

Answer (score 0):

finally i have to autowire the converter

Mvc-config
....

```
@Autowired
private GenericIdToCompanyConverter genericIdToCompanyConverter;
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(genericIdToCompanyConverter);
}
```

and update the converter like follow :

```
public class GenericIdToCompanyConverter implements GenericConverter {

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("companyService")
    private ICompanyService companyService;

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
       ....
    }
}
```